# Dataform `Operation could not be completed: Requested target does not exist in compilation results` error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt, dataform

I am new to Dataform, and am trying to set up an initial job.

I have a table of the form `database-1.schema.name`, which I can successfully query in the BigQuery environment for my project (call this project `database-0`).

When I moved the reference query into a `.sqlx` file, I was able to run the query and see results in a table.

However, when I executed the workflow I get the following error on failure:

```
Operation could not be completed: Requested target does not exist in compilation result: 'database-1.schema.name'.
```

I tried moving this table to a declaration, and the declaration fails with the same error. I tried this with a few different projects, and cannot get any declaration to execute successfully.

Is there a way to see valid target names, or to overcome this error? I have verified that the regions for the dataset and project are the same.

I am expecting that there is some easy fix that will allow me to successfully execute the workflow for a declaration.

Comment: When you run a query in DF, it runs under your own user and related permissions, but when you execute it, it runs as the DF service account. Does your service account have visibility of and permission to run on your project?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with GCP Dataform. If you have both the ***"BigQuery Data Editor"*** and ***"BigQuery Job User"*** roles assigned, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/required-access), you will be able to access the tables.

However, if you only have declaration statements in your repository, you may encounter the same error. To resolve this, simply **include a view script** in the declarations folder and initiate execution for all actions. This should eliminate the error. I hope this information helps.